# CALayer added to an UITextField do not appear on xib views

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, calayer, xib

I wanted to have some of my `UITextField`s with only a simple line under the text (and no borders). I create a little subclass of `UITextField` (I put it on Github so if you want to look at the code, you can go [there](https://github.com/Morniak/AmazingTextField)). I am using a `CALayer` with 1px height and I add it to my `UITextField`.

This is working fine for almost all my textFields but when I'm using it on the textFields in Xib files, the bottom line do not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Add the code below to your setProperties() method.

```
    layer.masksToBounds = false
```

Why's that fix the problem? Well, according to the documentation, a `CALayer`'s `masksToBounds` property defaults to `false`. A reasonable hypothesis would be that Apple's implementation of `UITextField`'s initWithCoder() initializer sets the view's layer's `masksToBounds` property to `true`, whereas their implementation of UITextField's initWithFrame() initializer does not. The inconsistency naturally leads to confusion, as shown here.

The code above guarantees that the layer's `masksToBounds` property will always be `false`, regardless of which initializer gets called.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I tried your solution and it didn't work.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "it didn't work?" Did you add a `UITextField` to your view controller's view in Interface Builder, set the text field's class to `AmazingTextField` in the Identity Inspector, and then build and run the application? When I do that, it does work. If on the other hand, you'd like a live preview of the `AmazingTextField` in Interface Builder, declare your `AmazingTextField` class `@IBDesignable`.

Comment: By "it didn't work" I mean when I compile and run the app, the `CALayer` is still missing (on the app not on the designer) for the views designed in xib files.

Comment: Could you upload the application that doesn't work to Github, so I could look it over?

Comment: I do not own the code so I can't share the whole project but I put the code of the `viewController` who load the xib files here : https://gist.github.com/Morniak/9884022f99f22898cbf0 (there is almost no code in the views linked to the xibs).